# One of the parameters is not assigned to user while sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Rails 4.1.1, Devise 3.2.4

I generated devise views to existing User model. And after that I added new field to users table - role. And edited generated Sign up view:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :role %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :role, User::ROLES, :to_s, lambda{|r| r.to_s.humanize} %>
  </div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

But when new user is signing up his role is `nil`. Form data from POST request is:

```
utf8:✓
authenticity_token:LEieRtzF0iYnhop/EzcU328Dyg1jKNT8DV5eqgkPERA=
user[email]:user4@test.com
user[password]:123123
user[password_confirmation]:123123
user[role]:author
commit:Sign up
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :rememberable, :registerable
  ROLES = %i[admin moderator author]
  has_many :products
end
```

Users schema:

```
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",               default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "role"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
```

So what is the issue?

```
>User.last
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 7, email: "user4@test.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$44A0uITgRB7DWvKInk3n1.YZyUPs6ZyKtKvMtPSfoi/...", username: nil, role: nil, remember_created_at: nil, created_at: "2014-06-15 08:03:06", updated_at: "2014-06-15 08:03:06">
```

Comment: If your User model contains a method 'roles', try changing `User:ROLES` by `USER:roles`

Comment: @sidney, User model don't have `roles` method. Provided model code

Comment: okay I see now thanks to your code. Please replace `%i` by `%` alone, like this: `ROLES = %[admin moderator author]`

Comment: If you still want to parse symbols, you can try this: `ROLES = %i(admin moderator author)`

Comment: Changed ROLES as you said. But still get `nil` in new user's role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rail 4 implements `strong parameters`, which require you to have a whitelist of params to be assigned to your model objects. This is meant to protect sensitive attributes from being overwritten by malicious users tampering with URLs or forms. Devise states that it permits some attributes for `sign_up`, `sign_in` and `account_update` actions by default, but it's your responsibility to append any additional parameters you would like by hands.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :role
  end
end
```

Take a look at

1. [Rails 4, Strong Parameters, and Deprecation of the Attr_accessible Macro](http://easyactiverecord.com/blog/2014/04/01/rails4-strong-parameters-and-the-attr-accessible-macro/)
2. [Devise wiki on strong params](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#getting-started/strong-parameters)